# Global dimension of $\prod k$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, global-dimension

Let $k$ be a field. Consider an infinite direct product of rings $\prod k$. This is an example of Von-Neumann regular ring (name also absolutely flat), that is, every module is flat.

I think this ring is nice! I have the following question:

**1. Is $\prod k$ self-injective?**

**2. What is the global dimension of $\prod k$ ? Finite or infinite? I have the feeling that it is infinite.**

I don't know how to deal with this question. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I only know for sure it is $>1$ (otherwise it would be hereditary+self-injective, which implies Artinian.) . You can prove it has infinite global dimension if you show that the projective dimensions of its cyclic modules are unbounded.

Comment: Actually [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/124598/19965) I see it claimed that $\prod_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb C$ has global dimension $2$!

Comment: @rschwieb how to show if R is hereditary and self-injective,then R is Artinian?thanks

Comment: *Osofsky, Barbara. "Rings all of whose finitely generated modules are injective." Pacific Journal of Mathematics 14.2 (1964): 645-650.* Corollary to the main Theorem.  It seems to be [open access at Project Euclid](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1103034192)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The global dimension of $\prod_\kappa F$ depends on the cardinalities $\kappa$ and $|F|$. It can be both finite or infinite. You will find very interesting material on that topic on [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/299700/19965).

(And yes as previously noted, any product of right self-injective rings is right self-injective.)

Answer (score 3):

The answer to question $1$ is that any product of fields is self-injective.

Actually, any product of self-injective rings is self-injective. See [Self-injective ring](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Self-injective_ring) on the Encyclopedia of Mathematics.